# Liferay portlet doView() back button issue

Tags: liferay, portlet, back-button

I have a portlet in Liferay 6.0 (GenericPortlet) with a redirect to a jsp page in the doView() method, problem is that with Chrome and Firefox if the user click the back button it seems the doView() method is not called at all.
Anyone had this problem? Any help would be really appreciated

Comment: what's the URL in the back button? It might be a URL that the browser has legitimately cached. Also (you probably don't have this, otherwise you'd know it) you can make portlets cacheable, which might lead to the whole page being cached server side - this would also not trigger a new render of the portlet.

Comment: Thanks Olaf, Yes the URL is cached by the browser.  I'l try to better explain my problem:

It's all about needing to access the current Organisation name (through ThemeDisplay object) from a Custom Servlet (GWT RPC Servlet).

To do so, in my doView method I set the ThemeDisplay object in a shared Session Variable (among the portlet and the servlet) which i successively read correctly in the servlet.

Everything's ok unless the user switches between 2 orgs using the back button of FF or Chrome. If this happens the doView Method do not get called, and the servlet reads the previous value

Comment: Please make your code more maintainable by not saving arbitrary framework-provided objects in sessions (I'm speaking of ThemeDisplay). Rather store exactly what you need to 1) keep your session small 2) not risk that the framework reuses the objects and they suddenly have different values 3) make sure that everything you have in the session is serializable. Also, please edit your question with the updates. You might consider to add code.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions Mr. Olaf, however even if I kept the solely organization name in the session the problem would still occur. Anyway it turned out it's not Liferay to blame, it's the browsers. Clicking back buttons makes the page to be fetched from browser's cache and not from the server, the JS code/ajax calls are still executed but since the portlet doView() is not executed the organization name remains the previous one stored in the session.